# Sorting DIVs vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently working on a design that requires multiple *<DIV>* elements sorted **vertically** but also keeping its ability to be responsive.

---

Examples:

#### Wider layout

[image: Wider layout]

#### Taller layout

[image: Taller layout]

---

I've used floats, inline-block display and even resorted to crudely putting it together with jQuery but all elements sort horizontally.

Looking around I can't seem to find any others with the same issue or solutions so any assistance would be great.

Comment: Those examples look like they are vertically "sorted". What's the problem?

Comment: The examples are how I'd like it to look. The result always ends up horizontal.

Comment: You should really show what you have tried (even if it doesn't work) and you should also tell use what exactly the problem is you are having. Otherwie it is impossible to help you

Comment: show us the code you tried, preferably on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Here's my attempt using jQuery to create a large enough area for them but sorting them vertically has me stumped: http://jsfiddle.net/reDcf/

Comment: Please show your relevant code here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not too concerned about cross-browser support (and just want to make it prettier in the compliant/up-to-date browsers), or are happy to use a JavaScript shim, of some kind, to enable support in other browsers, you could use `column-width` to define the width of the columns and then allow the browser to reflow those columns to accommodate the content:

```
.gridbox {
    display: block;
    -webkit-column-width: 4em;
    -moz-column-width: 4em;
    -o-column-width: 4em;
    -ms-column-width: 4em;
    column-width: 4em;
    /* aesthetics, adjust to taste,
       only the above is important */
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vvRm7/).

Clearly I've used `li` and `ul` elements for the purposes of the demo, but this is directly transferable to `div` elements if you prefer. Simply style the parent/container in the same fashion as the above `ul` element, and style the child elements as you like.

References:

- [CSS Multi-column layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).

Comment: This is great thanks! I'd not used `column-width` before. Older browsers aren't a major concern for me in this project. My analytics show ~1% non-compliant in the current traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to revamp your html structure a little bit. In order to do so you'd have to have sub-containers to your main container which would "group" your contents. Something like this:

```
// first example
<div id="main">
  <div class="group2">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>

// second example
<div id="main">
  <div class="group3">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Limiting the width of the group containers with css, you'd probably get the desired effect.

Comment: A good suggestion but I'm hoping to have a responsive layout that changes with the page dimensions. I suppose it may be possible to move the content into different groups with jQuery on resize.