# Snake (zig-zag) order of blocks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need snake sorting of HTML blocks. I can do it using `flex-direction: column`, but it works with constant container height only. I need flexible container height in depends on browser width. I want to get this result without JavaScript (or with simple code)

How it should work:

```
| ------------------------------------------------- |
| | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| |
| ------------------------------------------------- |
```

```
| --------------------------------- |
| | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| |
| --------------------------------- |
| | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |                 |
| -----------------                 |
```

```
| --------------------- |
| | 1 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 11| |
| --------------------- |
| | 2 | 5 | 8 | 10| 12| |
| --------------------- |
| | 3 | 6 |             |
| ---------             |
```

```
| ------------- |
| | 1 | 5 | 9 | |
| ------------- |
| | 2 | 6 | 10| |
| ------------- |
| | 3 | 7 | 11| |
| ------------- |
| | 4 | 8 | 12| |
| ------------- |
```

...

Comment: Add your current code please.

Comment: Try using the `column-width`. Link to [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997399/sorting-divs-vertically).

Comment: @Ihazkode I have no current code. Just I play here http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ and use chrome developer tools

Comment: @Zack It looks like what I need. Thanks!